# Pass variable in php to next page from a table

Tags: php, html-table

I'm creating a table and when the user clicks on the button I want it to open a php file called player_profile, where that page will call up more information on that particular player.

When it comes to passing variable through pages I'm aware that something along these lines will work.

```
//On page 1
$_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
```

Yet when I add it to the button the php file wont load. Below is my code without passing a variable that works.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, CONCAT(FirstName,' ', LastName) AS Name FROM Player WHERE     TeamID = '$TeamID' ORDER BY LastName ASC");
echo "<table id='customers' border='1'>
<tr>
<th>PlayerID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Tries</th>
<th>Tackles</th>
<th>Turnovers</th>
<th> Info </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row["PlayerID"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["Name"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Position'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Tries'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Tackles'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Turnovers'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><form action=player_profile.php>
<input name=id type=hidden value='".$row['PlayerID']."';>
<input type=submit name=submit value=info>
</form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tr>";  
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

The code above works perfectly at displaying a table and taking me to the player_profile page. But if change the button to the code below the page so that I can pass a variable it doesn't load

```
echo "<td><form action=player_profile.php>
<input name=id type=hidden value='".$row['PlayerID']."';>
$_SESSION['varname'] = ".$row['PlayerID'].";
<input type=submit name=submit value=info>
</form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: what r u trying to do here in `echo `-> `$_SESSION['varname'] = ".$row['PlayerID'].";`

Comment: Replace the third line with `". $_SESSION['varname'] . " = " . $row['PlayerID'].";`

Comment: @ManoloSalsas when i use that method inside the row i have it says playerid of the bottom entry = playeridof that row e.g 12 = 9 then the row below that has 12 = 7... when I click the button it takes me playerprofileid of 12 which is the bottom entry every time. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have code trying to set a session inside your echo. You want it separate:

```
echo "<td><form action=player_profile.php>
<input name=id type=hidden value='".$row['PlayerID']."'>   
<input type=submit name=submit value=info>
</form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

If you want to access the PlayerID variable on the player_profile.php you just use:

```
$var_value = $_GET['id'];
```

You could also put it into a session var at that point, but I don't know why you would need that.

Comment: Actually its only working for what ever is the bottom row in the table and not each individual row

Comment: I used your edited code and on player_profile entered $var_value = $_POST['id'];
echo "<p>" . $var_value . "</p>"; and it didnt echo the player id

Comment: If you click the button to get there it should work.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be carrying the variable over

Comment: i click the button it opens the player profile page but on the player profile page i want it to echo the value to make sure its there, and nothing is appearing

Comment: I don't know if that semicolon in the hidden var was messing it up; try removing that and `var_dump($_POST)` to see all the form values that get submitted.

Comment: changed the code then on the next page put `var_dump($_POST);` and got this `array(0) { }`

Comment: I just now noticed that you don't have `method="post"` in your form tag.... `$var_value = $_GET['id'];` will work instead or add the `POST` method.

Comment: Cheers mate all working now thanks for having so much patience with me

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the session to pass parameters. It breaks the way users expect a page works.

Use `$_GET` parameters:

```
<a href="player_profile.php?id=1235">John</a>
```

Then in `player_profile.php` do:

```
$id = isset($_GET["id"]) ? $_GET["id"] : false;
if ($id === false) {
    exit("missing input");
}
// etc
```

---

The problem with using a session here is that if someone opens two different player profiles what can he expect to see? What if he refreshes one of them?

---

A more advanced and involved way of parameter passing uses URL Rewriting to get nice looking URLs like:

```
<a href="/player/1234/John/profile">John</a>
```

Comment: Since you're reading data `GET` is correct here. `POST` is typically associated with modifying data. I think buttons are also wrong because of UX issues. You can always make a link that looks like a button.

Comment: OPs question is about passing parameters from one page to another. `GET` vs `POST` is relevant, db wrapper flavor is less relevant. If you want to do an in depth code analysis you're welcome to do it. Your comment is not constructive.